# What do the different /proc/bus/pci/0x directories represent?

Tags: linux, pci, pci-express, proc

What do the different /proc/bus/pci/0x directories represent?

Do they represent the different PCI/PCI-E sockets on a board?

If I have one mini pci and 2 PCI-E sockets on my board, should I be seeing 3 different '0x' directories under "/proc/bus/pci"?

Comment: The /proc directory usually stores volatile files used by processes. That just might be a file used by a process that interfaces with your pci slot. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from a friend - They represent PCI/PCI-E bridges present in the system. Usually each PCI slot is connected to a bridge - so it should show up in /proc/bus/pci. But its likely that /proc/bus/pci has more directories than PCI slots you can see

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that maps to your hardware, it exposes the PCI system data. But that interface is deprecated in favor of the /sys interface.

But you really should use the `lspci` command to find out about your devices, and not read those files directly.